# Export all data from custom button

Tags: export, bootstrap-table

Consider this example:
http://jsfiddle.net/wc0zLpef/219/

I am using `bootstrap-table` which is using `TableExport`

How can i export all data records by one click?
I tried adding:

```
$('#export').bootstrapTable('refreshOptions',{
  exportDataType: 'all'
});
```

or

```
  exportDataType: 'all',
  refreshOptions: { exportDataType: 'all'}
```

With normal button this works:

http://jsfiddle.net/ggywebtech/apseb49f/2/

But not with custom button.

Answer (score 1):

The first example you tried is attempting to instantiate a bootstrap table object on the element #export. What you want to do is call the bootstrap-table method on the #export element click event. I'm assuming the method syntax is correct.

```
$('#export').on('click',function(e) {
    $('#yourTableElement').bootstrapTable('refreshOptions', {exportDataType: 'all'})
})
```